# php return inside switch case is working but return after switch is not working

Tags: php, php-7

Can anyone help me with the following function, why `return` inside switch case is working (return correct converted price/quantity):

```
function calcPriceAndQuantityFromLBS($price, $quantity, $unit_id, $lbs_in_a_bu, $lbs_in_w_bu) {
    switch ($unit_id) {
        case 8: // A Bushel
            $outQ = $quantity / $lbs_in_a_bu;
            $outP = $price * $lbs_in_a_bu;
            return ['quantity' => number_format($outQ, 3, '.', ''), 'price' => number_format($outP, 8, '.', '')];
        case 10: // Pounds
            $outQ = $quantity;
            $outP = $price;
            return ['quantity' => number_format($outQ, 3, '.', ''), 'price' => number_format($outP, 8, '.', '')];
        case 11: // CWT
            $outQ = $quantity / LBS_IN_CWT;
            $outP = $price * LBS_IN_CWT;
            return ['quantity' => number_format($outQ, 3, '.', ''), 'price' => number_format($outP, 8, '.', '')];
        case 12: // Metric Tonne
            $outQ = $quantity / LBS_IN_TON;
            $outP = $price * LBS_IN_TON;
            return ['quantity' => number_format($outQ, 3, '.', ''), 'price' => number_format($outP, 8, '.', '')];
        case 136: // W Bushel
            $outQ = $quantity / $lbs_in_w_bu;
            $outP = $price * $lbs_in_w_bu;
            return ['quantity' => number_format($outQ, 3, '.', ''), 'price' => number_format($outP, 8, '.', '')];
    }
}
```

But this one is not? (return only `case 136` converted price/quantity) (`return` after switch is not working) How can I improve from the above one, I want to use less code to do the above function, thanks!

```
function calcPriceAndQuantityFromLBS($price, $quantity, $unit_id, $lbs_in_a_bu, $lbs_in_w_bu) {
    switch ($unit_id) {
        case 8: // A Bushel
            $outQ = $quantity / $lbs_in_a_bu;
            $outP = $price * $lbs_in_a_bu;
        case 10: // Pounds
            $outQ = $quantity;
            $outP = $price;
        case 11: // CWT
            $outQ = $quantity / LBS_IN_CWT;
            $outP = $price * LBS_IN_CWT;
        case 12: // Metric Tonne
            $outQ = $quantity / LBS_IN_TON;
            $outP = $price * LBS_IN_TON;
        case 136: // W Bushel
            $outQ = $quantity / $lbs_in_w_bu;
            $outP = $price * $lbs_in_w_bu;
    }
    return ['quantity' => number_format($outQ, 3, '.', ''), 'price' => number_format($outP, 8, '.', '')];
}
```

Comment: is your omision of "break" inside you switch statement cases intentional? cause as it stands now, no matter the value of $unit_id, case 136 is going to run last.

Comment: @victor oh right wow. I always use return before, forgot I need use break. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `break;` statement at the end of each `case`. Otherwise the code of the next `case`s of the `switch` statement will be executed too.
Your `return` statement uses variables that are defined in the `switch` statement. If somehow `$unit_id` is not in the list of `case`s, the `return` will fail in error. To prevent the `return` from failing, you could add this at the bottom of the case list:

```
default:  // $unit_id not found
  return ['quantity' => '0.000', 'price' => '0.000'];  // whatever you like
```

Or you could throw an Exception.

Comment: yes, since I use return all the time, forget I hae to use break, thanks!

Comment: that was def what jumped out at me first, but how does that effect the return statement not running?

Comment: @Code4R7 in fact the last one was executed... hm

Comment: `return` uses variables that are declared conditionally, so if `$unit_id` is not in the list of `case`s, the return statement fails in error.

Comment: @Code4R7 seems like it will keep fall down to next one, that's why I only got the last one. thanks, I will accept this in few min when it allowed me

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 2):

Return exits the function so in your case acts as a break, that is why it works in the first case.